# C# Email embedded image does not display in IE

Tags: c#, .net, image, internet-explorer, email

I am using C#.Net to send out a HTML email which contains embedded images. These emails work fine in Firefox and chrome but the images do not show up in Internet Explorer (IE). I know that the IE settings are not causing the problem since embedded images sent using Blat work just fine. Am I missing some option such as character set which is causing this problem? My code is as follows

```
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
 MailAddress from = new MailAddress("Myemail@MyDomain", "My Name");
 msg.To.Add("Myemail@MyDomain");
 msg.From = from;
 msg.Subject = "My subjecct line";

 AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is a sample JPG embedded image<br><img src=\"cid:image1.jpg\">", null, "text/html");

 LinkedResource EmbeddedObjects1 = new LinkedResource("PathToImage\\image1.jpg");
 EmbeddedObjects1.ContentId = "image1.jpg";
 htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(EmbeddedObjects1);

msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient("mailhost.domain.com", PortNumber);
smtpclient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Just taking a stab in the dark here, but try changing your `.ContentID =` to: `.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();'  The content id is a MIME thing, and having the '.' from the file extension might be confusing it.

Comment: Nothing displays in IE anymore ;)

Comment: Can you check what it shows as img tag src ?

Comment: I removed the "." as suggested but still no luck!
@Sonesh Dabhi, the img tag show up as <img src=3D"cid:image1"> (after I removed the .jpeg portion as suggested by Coding Gorilla)

Comment: You'd normally use an email reader instead of a browser.  Well, in the olden days anyway.  This is just as likely to be a problem with whatever server you are using.  They often produce different HTML based on the useragent string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps if you create the LinkedResource with a ContentType combined with Coding Gorilla's idea of a guid as the content-id:

```
Guid contentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
  "This is a sample JPG embedded image<br><img src=\"cid:" + contentId + "\">", 
  null, "text/html");

ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

LinkedResource EmbeddedObjects1 = new LinkedResource("PathToImage\\image1.jpg", ct);
EmbeddedObjects1.ContentId = contentId;
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(EmbeddedObjects1);
```

Comment: When I added the ContentType ct line and attached the linked resource to it (as shown above) it started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following.

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Additionally, I usually setup my AlternateView like this.

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, new ContentType("text/html"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Embedded images work by creating `dataUri` [schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). IE < 8 doesn't support those.